# Company is being shady about giving me a refund

Tags: united-states, california, consumer-protection, small-claims-court

I bought a product for ~1800 dollars. Their company states that as long as the product hasn't shipped, I can get a full refund.  They also say they have a 14 day money back guarantee even after the product arrives in my possession. This is all publicly stated on their website and I have screenshots of this, though its still on their website now.

The reason I wanted a refund is because their ship date of the product changed from Late June to Early August. I purchased the product on June 25th, under that assumption that it was going to ship soon, I requested a cancellation on June 28th, and have been trying to work this out ever since then. The problem is (which I will never do again) I order the product through interest free financing, so I cant cancel my order through a credit card or them (I've already contacted them).

This is a smallish company but has been around a while and has a lot of evidence of shipping products: I think this is a case of shady customer service and not shady products.

What has happened:
First I emailed them 3 times. No response. I posted on Reddit for advice on how to contact them, got the response to contact them via email, facebook and phone calls and to be relentless because they clearly avoid helping customers. I posted on their facebook with my complaint, then they responded to my email. In the email they asked me why I wanted to cancel, and if another product they offered that ships sooner would suit my needs. I said No, and I wanted to cancel my order. Days with no responses. During these days, I called them during their open hours and they never answered the phone. Finally, yesterday, I posted on their facebook again and got a response saying that they would contact me between 1-2 hours from then with details on my refund. They have now deleted that comment. I then called them and they finally picked up, and said that they would contact me via email about my refund. They have not contacted me, and I'm worried that they are just dodging me.

I want to know what my options are. I think my next step is to send a certified letter requesting my refund, despite the fact that I have record (email) that they know I've requested the refund. At this point it isn't a money thing. I can afford to lose out on the 1800 dollars, but I feel like i'm being taken for a ride. I'm willing to spend more to protect myself legally. I want to say something to them like,

"If I don't get a refund by date X, I will pursue legal action to get it, something we all want to avoid but may be necessary considering the nature of your actions."

I am not the only one who has trouble contacting them. They have a long list of message boards who have this complaint (I did not do my research, I got seduced by the spectacle of the product, I've totally learned my lesson).

Comment: Where are you, and where is the company?

Comment: I am in southern california they are in northern california.

Answer (score 0):

If you have paid by credit card, contact the credit card company and ask that they reverse the charges.

An alternative would be to sue them in a court of limited jurisdiction, having a process server deliver the the summons and complaint to their registered agent (assuming that there is no arbitration clause in the agreement between the parties). They have breached their contract and you are entitled to a remedy as a result for their breach.

If they are blowing you off to the extent that it seems that they are, I would not bother with making further demands or negotiations.

Answer (score 0):

A certified letter, stating your simple claim for refund, and citing all of your specific previous contact attempts, for the record, would be a good start. You might soft-pedal the legalese, giving them the benefit of the doubt (could be some incompetent noob handling your case). But you still want them to understand you have been more than patient and you are exploring further steps, in the event they don't immediately answer and address their mistake to your satisfaction.